# PMD-Plugin in Eclipse/Juno not installable through marketplace

Tags: eclipse, pmd, eclipse-juno, eclipse-marketplace

I recently upgraded from Eclipse (for Java/EE developers, x64) "Indigo" to "Juno". Unluckily the PMD-Plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pmd-eclipse) does not seems to be available for this product.

I was unable to find another way of installing this product into my new eclipse, can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: I opened a ticket at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3545849&group_id=56262&atid=479924 . Looks like I'm a bit toooo early for this feature. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Version for Juno](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/) now available.

Comment: Explain your answer - rather than just providing a link... That way, it will be more applicable to far more users.

Comment: Add this Update site to your eclipse: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/   (That is the linke above)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using PMD 3.2.6 with Juno without any difficulties.  Have you tried pointing to the "PMD for Eclipse 3" repository?  (I upgraded by letting [Eclipse upgrade my plugins](http://www.selikoff.net/2012/07/01/eclipse-juno-4-2-review/), but I think that is equivalent to installing from scratch for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Ok, so just to be >=100% sure: you suggest using the "PMD for Eclipse 3" repository for an Eclipse 4, which works with your installation?

Comment: Right.  While I didn't install explicitly (because Eclipse migrated the plugin from Indigo (3.7), it is clearly working in Juno (4.2).  At worst, the installer won't like it.  But the plugin itself works.  So if you get past the installer, you will be set!

Comment: After complaining a lot about ssl-certificates, it worked pretty well. I'll leave the ticket at sourceforge open as well and hope, that PMD will install some day through marketplace. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have found the update site for the juno version of the plugin. It is no longer on the old update site.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

Answer (score 1):

What about installng through a regular Eclipse update site? See http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/

Comment: Unluckily the repositories include "PMD for Eclipse 2" and "PMD for Eclipse 3" only.